# Font stacked horizontally in chrome on ~10% of pageloads

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome

I get this annoying visual bug on about 10% of pageloads in chrome (all resources loads correctly).

[image: font stacking]

The site is build with ASP.net, bootstrap and uses the "Neuzeit S LT W01 Book" font.

Any ideas what might be causing it?

```
<div class="center-block block text-left">

    <h3>Welcome!</h3>
    <p>
        At Kidbrooke Advisory we are passionate about enabling organisations to analyse financial risk.
        The specific needs will of course vary from company to company; the requirements of a large insurance 
        company subject to recent EU regulations are markedly different from the ones of a small energy company.
    </p>
    <p>
        We at Kidbrooke Advisory excel at providing bespoke <a href="/WhatWeDo/">risk analysis solutions</a>, 
        tailored to the specific business needs of your organisation.
    </p>
    <p>
        Please <a href="/WhatWeDo/">read on</a> for more information about how we could help your 
        organisation better understand the financial risks you are facing.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: when inspecting the html, are they separate elements that get aligned wrong? Or is it in the middle of a block of text? i see some misaligned links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty obscure issue, but it's most definitely a browser bug. It happened to me a few weeks ago, and I came across this thread where it has been discussed in detail: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/tYHSqc-fqso

The problem is that Chrome doesn't update the widths of your elements after the font loads. It renders the page as if you're using the default font.

No one knows why it happens. That thread is from 2014 and the issue still occurs today, but it's only ever happened to me on one website. I can only assume that the bug is triggered by specific fonts.

There is a solution. It's a hack, but it works.

If you hide the body and show it again, it will force a reflow, which seems to fix the issue. So, if you're using jQuery, something like this will do the trick (make sure it's in your `.ready()` function):

```
$('body').hide().show();
```

Comment: I've experimented with it and it seems to fix a broken page if the hide() and show() calls have some time between them. hide().show() or hide();show(); does not seem to do the trick unfortunately.

Comment: @SverkerSbrg It's definitely in the `document.ready()` function, right? You could also try putting it in `document.load`. I assume a delay would be undesirable, as you'll see the website flash while it waits to show it again.

Comment: I run it via console after load. The following seems to do the trick with minimal disturbance. ---- var elem = $(".center-block")
var width = elem.outerWidth();
elem.css("width", width +1 );
setTimeout(function(){
   $(elem).css("width", width);
},20);

Comment: @SverkerSbrg Awesome, I'm glad you were able to get a fix working. *shakes fist at Chrome*